# Need help w/ FuelUX "Scheduler" Javascript control

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, fuel

Here's the link to the documentation:
http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/javascript.html#scheduler

If I use the "data-initialize" attribute (see below), is there a way to still use Javascript to programmatically access the scheduler?

`<div class="form-horizontal container-fluid scheduler" role="form" data-initialize="scheduler" id="myScheduler">
.....
scheduler stuff in here
</div>`

FYI, the data-initialize attribute allows the developer to not have to use a line of Javascript to instantiate or use the scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the docs for this control, I see:

> To enable the scheduler control without writing Javascript, add
>   data-initialize="scheduler" to the .scheduler element that you wish to
>   initialize. Such elements that exist when $.ready() executes will be
>   initialized. Any scheduler markup that is programatically created with
>   data-initialize="scheduler" sometime after the initial page load will
>   not immediately initialize. Rather, it will initialize when the
>   mousedown event is fired on it.

That being said, it would appear that using the declarative syntax for instantiating the control may not have some race-cases which could occur.

Regardless, you CAN gain access to the control through normal jQuery selector syntax once it has been initialized via the declarative style (data-initializer="scheduler" on the .scheduler DOM element).

I have created a JSFiddle that shows you how to do it properly.
http://jsfiddle.net/bdeanet/py5mnqkk/10/

Please let me know if you have any questions.

-benjamin-